# Should questions asking for help with debugging code be marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If someone asks a question that has been previously asked/answered, obviously that is a duplicate question.

However, if someone posts a question asking for assistance with code that implements the same logic another question has already asked, is that too a duplicate?

E.g. new user posts this question:
[Not getting correct output for merge sort in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70105943/not-getting-correct-output-for-merge-sort-in-python)

Which is closely related to this question: [mergesort python implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480851/mergesort-python-implementation)

Comment: Do the two questions have exactly the same solution? Is the code flawed in, and /or can it be fixed in, precisely the same way? If so, then, yes, they're duplicates.

Comment: So there is a canonical [Merge Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18761766/15497888) for python which I _may_ reference in a comment or an answer if wanting to provide access to potentially "better" ways to address the issue, but _if_ this question were to be closed as a duplicate it should address the _specific issues_ being faced by the current poster, not necessarily the problem they are trying to solve. For example, if the issue is indentation (something is indented too far or not far enough) I'd use a duplicate about indentation whether or not it was about Merge Sort specifically.

Comment: Are you asking about this *specific* case or is it just an example for the *general* case?

Comment: E.g. means *exempli gratia* in Latin, which means “for example.” So yes the general case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the questions cover the same topic and the answer can apply to both questions equally with very minimal ambiguity if any at all, then that's a duplicate, and the question should be closed as such.

If they diverge in specific spots or implementations - for instance if the user was using a specific data structure to implement 90% of the behavior - then I would hesitate to call a question which didn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the question isn't "how do I implement merge sort in Python" but rather "what is wrong with my implementation of merge sort in Python".

For the debug questions to be duplicates they must contain the same bug. Being about the same topic doesn't necessarily make them duplicates. At a glance, it would appear that one of the posts is an array out of bounds bug and the other some incorrect function call.